# Forçar um click em uma tag a com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quero que quando o meu `<li>` seja clicicado, ele ative um click na tag `<a>` que está dentro dele.

```
<li class="tab card-panel z-depth-1 ativado historia hoverable">
                <a href="#historia" class="active a">
                  <div class="row valign-wrapper">
                    <div class="col s2">
                      <i class="zmdi zmdi-assignment zmdi-hc-2x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s10">
                      <span class="">
                        <b>SOBRE NÓS</b>
                      </span> <br>
                      <span class="">
                        Lore inpsulum dolor fech assoc
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
```

Como posso fazer isso com Jquery ?

Comment: que quer dizer com ative um click? que a ação do link seja executada?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo Léo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui pessoal, foi simples :

```
$(li).click(function{
  $("li > a")[0].click();
});
```

*Respondi minha própria pergunta porque alguém pode ter a mesma duvida um dia.*

Comment: ou tambem poderia usar $("li").click(function{ $("li > a").trigger("click"); });